# Custom Variables and Utm.gif request

Tags: google-analytics

I thought my custom variables were finally working, but I'm not sure anymore. As someone suggested I used fiddler to check the **utm.gif** request to see if my custom variables were sending, but I can't tell for certain.

The utm.gif request does not contain the "**utme**" parameter that is used for events and custom variables, but it does have at the very end a "**gaq**" parameter with a value of **1**.

So, while I don't have the "utme" parameter I do have a "gaq" parameter with a value that matches the slot I use. I'm not sure if this means Google is sending the custom variable or not.

In the Google Analytic reports my custom variables started showing up 2 - 3 days after I set them and then each day after with new values. Now it has been a couple of days again and the data is not being recorded. There has been absolutely no change to my site or analytics code.

I also notice that in the "**User Defined**" section of the reports that I have a **(not set)** value for each visit. My guess is this could be the Custom Variable data, I'm not sure.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste in the value of the utm.gif request? The _gaq value just means you're using the async code; it has nothing to do with custom variables.

Comment: Hi yc, here is a sample request. I tweaked account and site name, everything else is the same.



http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?
utmwv=4.7.2
&utmn=273585367
&utmhn=my.site.com
&utmcs=UTF-8
&utmsr=1680x1050
&utmsc=24-bit
&utmul=en-us
&utmje=1
&utmfl=10.1%20r53
&utmhid=2005010749
&utmr=0
&utmp=%2FPlanner
&utmac=UA-XXXXXXX-1
&utmcc=__utma%3D226196228.2194197.1279582521.1281211250.1281222826.25%3B%2B__utmz%3D226196228.1279582521.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B
&gaq=1

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the utme information was not being sent, even though I was calling `_setCustomVar(slot,name,value,scope)`.  In my case it was because the length of name+value was more than 64 characters.  GA has a 64 char limit for this.  From [Google Analytics - Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#varTypes):

> All custom variable types can be defined for a combined length of 64 bytes inclusive of the name and the value.  This means that the length of the string used for the name and the length of the string used for the value must not exceed 64 bytes.